# Multiple updates and re-sequence rows

Tags: sql

Hi Guys I need your help with multiple updates:

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
Start date, seqID,  Name
07/07/2013  1       Name1
07/09/2013  2       Name2
07/11/2013  3       Name3
07/15/2013  4       Name4
07/20/2013  5       Name5
```

If start date 07/15/2013 is changed to 07/10/2013 then seq ID 4 becomes 3 and the row becomes after 07/09/2013, seq ID 2

If Start Date 07/09/2013 is changed to 07/16/2013 then the row is re-sequenced as number 4 and moved to above 07/20/2013:

The update would be as follows:

```
Start date, seqID,  Name
07/07/2013  1       Name1
07/11/2013  2       Name3
07/15/2013  3       Name4
07/16/2013  4       Name2
07/20/2013  5       Name5
```

How can I re-sequence the seqID when date is updated?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your RDBMS but mostly your sequence will be dynamic on the output.

SQL Server 2005 + & Oracle (and maybe others) have  ROW_NUMBER() function which you'd use to establish the sequence number as you select the data you need based on the ordering criteria.